# Clarification in model precision term for Gaussian Processes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Following the [blog post](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/blog_3d801aa532c1ce.html), where the dropout in the deep learning models has been approximated to a Gaussian process. [Research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02142.pdf) and its [appendix](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02157.pdf).

Looking at the suggestion of the author from the blog post that the variance in the prediction is given by the following piece of code. I found it counterintuitive as the predictive variance is directly proportional to the number of observations. `tau` -- which author refers as model precision.

I have tried to go through the research paper but it seems I don't have enough skills to comprehend the reasoning behind it.

Shouldn't the variance decrease with the more observations?

```
probs = []
for _ in xrange(T):
    probs += [model.output_probs(input_x)]
predictive_mean = numpy.mean(prob, axis=0)
predictive_variance = numpy.var(prob, axis=0)
tau = l**2 * (1 - model.p) / (2 * N * model.weight_decay)
predictive_variance += tau**-1
```